# ¿Cómo validar que no se quede pegado el procedimiento c# / oracle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedure

El problema es el siguiente, tengo una aplicación en c# que llama a un procedimiento en oracle para insertar los datos de un archivo txt en una tabla.
Este es código en c# que llama al procedimiento.

```
public string InsertarVentas(string fechatxt, int codestacion, string fechaProceso)
        {
            try
            {
                string respuesta = "";

                OracleConnection conexion = new OracleConnection(ConexcionDA.CadenaConexion());


                OracleCommand comando = new OracleCommand("INSERT_VENTAS_DETALLADAS", conexion);

                comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comando.Parameters.Add("codestacion", OracleType.VarChar).Value = codestacion;
                comando.Parameters.Add("fechaProceso", OracleType.VarChar).Value = fechaProceso;
                comando.Parameters.Add("txt", OracleType.VarChar).Value = codestacion.ToString() + fechatxt + ".txt";

                OracleDataReader reader;
                conexion.Open();

                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conexion.Close();
                conexion.Dispose();
                comando.Dispose();

                return "ok";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "error: " + e;
            }
        }
```

El procedimiento en oracle es este:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_VENTAS_DETALLADAS(
codestacion VARCHAR,
fechaProceso VARCHAR2,
txt VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN
declare
          stmt varchar2(2000) := 'CREATE or replace DIRECTORY USER_DIR AS ''/home/interfaz/VentasGNV/Temp''' ;
        begin
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
        end;

DECLARE
      V1 VARCHAR2(20000);
      V2 VARCHAR2(20000);
      SQLSTMT VARCHAR2(2000);
      EMP_FILE UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
      V3 VARCHAR2(20000);
      V4 VARCHAR2(20000);
BEGIN
      delete from VENTA_DETALLADA_TEST where COD_ESTACION = codestacion and FECHA_PROCESO = (select TO_DATE(fechaProceso,'DD/MM/YY') from dual);
      EMP_FILE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('USER_DIR',txt,'R');
      LOOP
      BEGIN     



        UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(EMP_FILE,V1);

        SELECT REPLACE(V1,';;',';null;') INTO V1 FROM DUAL;
        V3 := ''||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 1)||''','''||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 2)||''','''||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 3)||''','''||TO_DATE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 4),'[^ ]+', 1, 1) ,'DD/MM/YY')||''','''||TO_DATE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 5),'[^/]+', 1, 2)||'/'||REGEXP_SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 5),'[^/]+', 1, 1)||'/'||REGEXP_SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 5),'[^/]+', 1, 3) ,'DD/MM/YY')||''','''||TO_DATE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 6),'[^ ]+', 1, 1) ,'DD/MM/YY')||''','''||TO_DATE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 7),'[^ ]+', 1, 1) ,'DD/MM/YY')||''','''||TO_DATE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 8),'[^ ]+', 1, 1) ,'DD/MM/YY')||''','''||TO_DATE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 9),'[^ ]+', 1, 1),'DD/MM/YYYY')||''','||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 10)||','||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 11)||','''||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 12)||''','||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 13)||','||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 14)||','||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 15)||','||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 16)||','||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 17)||','||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 18)||','||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 19)||','''||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 20)||''','''||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 21)||''','||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 22)||','''||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 23)||''','''||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 24)||''','''||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 28)||''','''||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 29)||''','''||REGEXP_SUBSTR (V1, '[^;]+', 1, 30)||'''';
        SQLSTMT := 'INSERT INTO VENTA_DETALLADA_TEST(COD_ESTACION,SERIE,NUMERO,SERIE_MAQ,FECHA_VENTA,FECHA_PROCESO, FEC_TURNO_APERTURA,  FEC_TURNO_CIERRE,   FEC_INICIO_LECTURA, FEC_FIN_LECTURA, LECTURA_INICIAL,  LECTURA_FINAL,  RUC,  CANTIDAD, PRECIO_UNITARIO, RECAUDO,  VALOR_VENTA, IGV,   PRECIO_VENTA, MANGUERA, PLACA, CARA,  RECIBO, COD_ISLA, COD_TURNO, SURTIDOR,  TARJETA_FIDELIZACION,  TARJETA_FLOTA, ESTADO)  VALUES('''||codestacion||''','''||V3||',0)';
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLSTMT); 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLSTMT;
        EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
        begin
          UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(EMP_FILE);

          COMMIT;

          declare
            stmt varchar2(2000) := 'drop DIRECTORY USER_DIR' ;
          begin
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
          end;

          declare
            salida varchar2(2000) := 'select ''ok''  respuesta from dual' ;
          begin
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE salida;
          end;

          EXIT;
        end;
      END;
      END LOOP;

END;

END;
```

Lo que pasa es que la llamada se puede ejecutar n veces, y hay momentos en los que pruebo y todas las llamadas se dan correctamente pero otras veces no avanza de la primera llamada.
Entonces lo que tengo que hacer es ir a la bd y ejecutar esta linea:

```
CREATE or replace DIRECTORY USER_DIR AS '/home/interfaz/VentasGNV/Temp'
```

Después de ejecutarla todos las llamadas siguientes se ejecutan correctamente.
No se exactamente que es lo que pasa si es un tema de lógica en c# o en oracle, o porque se está quedando pegando y no avanza.

Es pero puedan ayudarme o brindarme una idea de como corregirlo. 
Gracias.

Comment: Cuantas consultas haces?? se estara llenando la carpeta de archivos???

Comment: El número de consultas varias según un rango de fecha, por ejemplo del 01/01/2018 al 18/01/2018 por lo que se harán 18 llamadas, los archivos que se van a leer por cada fecha ya se encuentran en el directoria que se especifica.

Comment: abra algun otro proceso en el server que este usando USER_DIR ?

Comment: nada, ya le cambie de nombre pero igual, ahora en la linea comando.ExecuteNonQuery(), donde se queda pegado, no produce error, simplemente no avanza.

Comment: Pq esta esperando la respuesta del SP que es el que se queda colgado... dira algo en la bd?? algun tipo de error?

Comment: hace un momento acabo de probar el sp en la bd durante la ejecución en c# y cuando lo ejecute avanzo normalmente del Execute command

Comment: ahora en mi ultima prueba le comente esto:
delete from VENTA_DETALLADA_TEST where COD_ESTACION = codestacion and FECHA_PROCESO = (select TO_DATE(fechaProceso,'DD/MM/YY') from dual);
y ahora parece que ya no se detiene y pasa normal, aún estoy probando.

Comment: Estas teniendo una race condition en la BD que traba el proceso del SP.. no se como ayudarte un poco mas :(